# Sun Grid Engine (SGE) e-mail notification from master server

Tags: sungridengine

I'm going to use e=mail notification of job status by using "#$ -M" options.
But the problem is that our compute nodes are blocked to connect internet. So the compute node cannot send e-mail to user.
Can I send the e-mail from Master server instead of compute node ??

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that a regular user can do but the cluster administrator could set up a mail server on the Master server and configure the cluster nodes to use it as a smarthost.